# How to configure the log cat when developing for flutter

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

When flutter has an error, the stacktrace is printed in the console however for subsequent errors I only get:

```
Another exception was thrown: short description of my error
```

Is there a way to configure android studio to display every error in its entirety with a full stack trace? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, https://flutter.io/docs/resources/bug-reports explains how to modify flutter to use `Verbose` mode in producing logs and where to locate them. According to the flutter website:

> All Flutter commands accept the `--verbose` flag. If attached to the
>   issue, the output from this command may aid in diagnosing the issue.

The explanation was done using `xcode`, but it should not be a concern since since Flutter configuration are independent from IDEs'.

Comment: thanks this helped, i couldnt see an option for verbose as it turns out my logcat was not configured in android studio and i was looking at the run logs, after configuring the android studio logcat and switching to verbose there it now works for every error many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When that happens, it means that the error is exactly like the one before. There's no need to see it again, as it would just clutter the logs.

If flutter showed you all of the errors everytime, there's a high chance your output log would be big, incomprehensible, and impractical to use, specially because sometimes if you just touch something, move something, rebuild a screen, some errors can happen multiple times.

So I don't see that as something necessary, much less advisable.

Comment: i understand why it does it however in my scenario the app always throws this first error and i know about it and will be fixing it at a later date, but i could do with the second error as thats what i would be currently working on, thanks anyway though